# Weibull survival regression variance-covariance matrix

Tags: r, survival, covariance-matrix

Do I have to perform any transformation on the variance-covariance matrix computed by either `survreg` or `flexsurvreg`? Also, the covariance values have opposite signs between those two functions. Why?

Example:

```
fitw <- survreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ 1, data = ovarian, dist="weibull")
fitw$var
        (Intercept) Log(scale)
(Intercept)  0.08568966 0.03385160
Log(scale)   0.03385160 0.06431534

fitw$icoef
(Intercept)  Log(scale) 
7.1110381  -0.1026105 


fitw2 <- flexsurvreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ 1, data = ovarian, dist="weibull")
fitw2$cov
        shape       scale
shape  0.06431532 -0.03385157
scale -0.03385157  0.08568962

fitw2$coefficients
shape     scale 
0.1026105 7.1110381
```

Ultimately, I'd like to construct bounds on reliability as explained [here](https://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue17/relbasics17.htm). So I'll need the variances of $\beta$ (shape) and $\eta$ (scale), as well as the covariance between them. And I guess its sign matters. What about the units? Should I apply any transformation to the values calculated by those two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be very careful with just how the Weibull distribution is parameterized within a function, as there are [alternate choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Alternative_parameterizations). You will note that the value and the variance for the `Intercept` in the first model are the same as those for `scale` in the second, and the value  for `log(scale)` in the first model is the negative of the `shape` in the second, with the same variances, indicating that the parameterizations differ between the models. The help page for `survreg` explains:

> There are multiple ways to parameterize a Weibull distribution. The `survreg` function embeds it in a general location-scale family, which is a different parameterization than the `rweibull` function, and often leads to confusion.

> `survreg`'s scale  =    1/(`rweibull` shape)

> `survreg`'s intercept = log(`rweibull` scale)

The manual page for `flexsurvreg` says:

> The Weibull parameterisation is different from that in survreg, instead it is consistent with dweibull. The "scale" reported by survreg is equivalent to 1/shape as defined by dweibull and hence flexsurvreg. The first coefficient (Intercept) reported by survreg is equivalent to log(scale) in dweibull and flexsurvreg.

The manual page for `dweibull` describes its parameterization as:

> The Weibull distribution with shape parameter a and scale parameter b has density given by

> f(x) = (a/b) (x/b)^(a-1) exp(- (x/b)^a), for x > 0.

That parameterization by `dweibull` agrees with that [referred to](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/The_Weibull_Distribution) by the [reliability measure you cite](https://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue17/relbasics17.htm), with the `dweibull` shape `a` corresponding to shape $\beta$ and the `dweibull` scale `b` corresponding to scale $\eta$.

Be ruthlessly consistent in the parameterization. It would seem to be safest here to use the `flexsurvreg` parameterization, as that agrees with your intended downstream use. The confidence intervals based on the covariance matrix just use the coefficient estimates and their (co)variances directly, so there's no need to transform. Even then, look at plots, check carefully, and make sure that things make sense whenever you come upon a potentially confusing parameterization like you face with the Weibull distribution.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that elements in indices `[1,1]` and `[2,2]` are swapped between `fitw$var` and `fitw2$cov`. My main concern is if I should transform those values to follow the parametrization that uses $\beta$ and $\eta$ in the other link. Also, the opposite signs for the off-diagonal elements is strange.

Comment: @Bruno my guess is that there is also a sign difference in one of the corresponding coefficient values between the two models. Please edit the question to include the actual coefficient estimates for the two models, not just the covariance matrices, to help make sure. Weibull parameterization differences provide many places where things can go unexpectedly wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question with the cofficients. Now it's clear where the sign difference comes from. Still not clear if I should use the positive value for the covariance in order to be compatible with the $\beta$ and $\eta$ parametrization. The remaining question is if I need to apply any transformation to the variance-covariance matrix at all.

Comment: @Bruno added more to the answer to deal with your last comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)