# Predict expected survival after n months with survreg weibul

Tags: r, survival, weibull-distribution

Context is a subscription business with a monthly cost. Goal is to understand expected lifetime of a subscription.

I have a weibul model via survreg package:

```
wb <-survreg(Surv(time = interval, event = censored) ~ 1, data = .x, dist = 'weibull')
 summary(wb)

Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(time = interval, event = censored) ~ 1, 
    data = .x, dist = "weibull")
              Value Std. Error     z      p
(Intercept)  2.0914     0.0142 147.6 <2e-16
Log(scale)  -0.1711     0.0131 -13.1 <2e-16

Scale= 0.843 

Weibull distribution
Loglik(model)= -11482.7   Loglik(intercept only)= -11482.7
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 5 
n= 6618
```

In this case there are no covariates, just a simple model.

Using predict, I can compute the expected survival, in this model in months, of a new observation (See [predict.survreg on this pdf](http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf)).

```
predict(wb, newdata = data.frame(1), type = 'response')
       1 
8.096338
```

This, as I understand it, tells me that a new subscription is expected to last just over 8 months.

My question is, is it possible to calculate survival after 1:12 months? Is there a way that I can use `predict()` to compute the probability of a new subscription remaining in month1, month2, month3, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for survreg.distributions says:

"The location-scale parameterization of a Weibull distribution found in survreg is not the same as the parameterization of rweibull"

and

"survreg scale parameter maps to 1/shape, linear predictor to log(scale)"

So, I would try estimating the survival at months 1:12 by

1-pweibull(1:12,shape=1/exp(-0.1711),scale=exp(2.094))

Answer (score 2):

With a parametric survival model, you have the advantage of a closed-form expression for the survival probability as a function of time. With a continuous distribution like the Weibull, the [survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function#Definition) is simply $1-F(t)$, where $F(t)$ is the cumulative distribution function. For the Weibull in the [standard parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Standard_parameterization):

$$F(t;k,\lambda) = 1- \mathrm{e}^{-(t/\lambda)^k}$$

so the survival function is:

$$ S(t;k,\lambda) = \mathrm{e}^{-(t/\lambda)^k}.$$

Once you've established the parameter values from your model, you plug in the value of time $t$ and get your point estimate of survival up to that time. Unfortunately, there are [several parameterizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Alternative_parameterizations) of the Weibull, so you have to pay attention to [which parameterization your software is using](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/489529/28500).

To get a nice plot of survival over time with confidence intervals, the last example on the manual page for `predict.survreg` shows how to proceed. The trick is to use the "quantile" type of prediction while specifying a large range of quantiles (e.g., 1st to 98th; the 100th is at infinite time) and plot each survival percentage along the vertical axis against its corresponding predicted time, plus/minus confidence intervals.