# What is the meaning of the flexsurvreg plot and its res.t?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, weibull-distribution, accelerated-failure-time

I use the flexsurverg to estimate the a Weibull survival model with a time varied covariate, where “utility” is a continuous function, and the result is shown as follows:

[image]

I plot the fit function and it provides a survival function figure(red line),

[image]

I wonder what is the formulation of this survival function in figure and what is the relationship between the parameters estimated and this survival function.

(I try to use the estimated parameters from res.t into the standard Weibull acceleration failure model to generate the survival function but the figure is different as shown)

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about the nature of `utility`: is that a binary or a continuous predictor? If continuous, what is its typical range of values? It's also not clear what the black and red survival curves are meant to distinguish. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicted survival curves involving time-varying covariates, as you have, are troublesome at best. Some software even refuses to let you try to make such predictions, with those managing the packages arguing that such predictions involve a type of circular logic: if you know that an individual's covariate value has changed at some time after the starting `time = 0`, then you know that the individual has already survived that long.

So what type of predicted overall survival curve might be plotted? According to Section 3.4 of the [`flexsurv` user guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/vignettes/flexsurv.pdf)

> The `plot()` method for `flexsurvreg` objects is used as a quick check of model fit. By default, this draws a Kaplan-Meier estimate of the survivor function $S(t)$, one for each combination of categorical covariates, or just a single “population average” curve if there are no categorical covariates ... The corresponding estimates from the fitted model are overlaid.

As you had no categorical covariates, the red predicted curve is presumably just a Weibull survival curve based on the `shape` and `scale` parameters estimated in the model and a "population average" value of `utility` kept constant in time. I'm not completely sure how that package calculates the "population average" covariate value of your `utility` predictor, but I suspect that it's the "data mean" of 0.512 shown in the model output. That the theoretical curve doesn't fit the Kaplan-Meier curve (which I infer to be the black line with steps) isn't surprising, given that the covariate values were changing over time in your data.

There are different ways to parameterize Weibull distributions. There's also a question of parameter transformation for display. The `shape` and `scale` coefficients shown in `a$res.t` are the logarithms of those shown in the original table of estimates.*

With parametric models you have to pay close attention to the manual for the particular software that you are using to make sure that you are interpreting the coefficients correctly. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/489516/28500) discusses the differences between the standard `survreg()` and `flexsurvreg()`. The interpretations might also differ depending on whether you use the proportional-hazards or accelerated failure time options for the Weibull distribution with `flexsurvreg()`. Once you find the correct transformation and interpretation of the parameters, and resign yourself to using a single time-constant average value of `utility` (probably 0.512), you should be able to match the shape of the continuous Weibull curve shown in the plot.

---

*It seems that the values in the `a$reg.t` output are those in the original fit, given the symmetry of the CI about the point estimates. Those are then exponentiated to get the corresponding values in the table of `Estimates`, like hazard ratios are exponentiations of the log-hazard scale coefficients in Cox models.