# How to estimate the variance covariance matrix of a Weibull survival model manually?

Tags: survival, weibull-distribution

In flexsurv the var-covar matrix of the parameters can be produced with the vcov() function. This will produce a var-ovar matrix for the shape and scale parameters provided by the function coef(). Rather than use shape, I want to find the var-covar for m = exp(scale)^(-exp(shape)) and scale. I was wondering how I would do this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: I'm trying to replicate some analysis done in Stata. Stata reports different parameters and so a different var-covar matrix.

Comment: oftentimes, people like to use the diagonal elements of the negative inverse Hessian of the likelihood wrt the parameters (evaluated at the MLE) as variances, and then to form standard 95% intervals assuming normality.

Comment: Please edit the question to say why you want to find that matrix. The variance-covariance matrix makes the most sense when coefficient estimates have an asymptotic multivariate normal distribution, which wouldn't seem to be the case after your transformation. I suspect that there is a better way to address the underlying problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I've edited the question for why I'm trying to do this

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method

Comment: what is paramterization for Weibull? there are close to 11 or 13 parameterization for weibull.

Comment: Besides [multiple Weibull parameterizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Alternative_parameterizations) there are [2 different ways to express covariate associations](https://www.stata.com/manuals/ststreg.pdf) in survival models: one for proportional-hazards (PH) and one for accelerated-failure-time (AFT) interpretation. I think that the defaults are PH in Stata and AFT in the [`flexsurv` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=flexsurv). Are you sure that you are using the same parameterizations in both systems? That would be the most reliable way to check.

Comment: Yes I was using the incorrect one ‍♂️ I've switched to PH now and it works. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489516/weibull-survival-regression-variance-covariance-matrix/489529#489529 is another example of this type of all-too-frequent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you want an analytical answer, which I'm sure at least approximately with some series expansions or the like should be obtainable in this kind of case.

However, it's a lot simples to use simulation methods. You simply sample parameter values for `shape` and `scale` from the multivariate normal (e.g. using the `mvtnorm` package) for the given mean vector (i.e. the parameter estimates) and variance-covariance matrix. Then, you calculate for each sample the transformation you want to get `m`. Finally, you can calculate the variance covariance matrix between the resulting samples of `m` and the existing samples of `scale` (of course making sure to keep the same order of the vectors).